# how to know if https server is one way ssl or two way ssl

Tags: java, python, ssl, https, openssl

Since I am new to this SSL I am asking this question. I googled and got this below mentioned HTTPS server python script. May I please know if its one way SSL or Two way SSL? And also how do I take dump to see the communication between client and server?

My requirement is to have one way SSL.

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='path/to/localhost.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May I please know if its one way SSL or Two way SSL

This is one-way, i.e. the server is sending its certificate but not requesting a certificate from the client. The server could request a client certificate by adding `cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED` to the call of `ssl_wrap`.

> And also how do I take dump to see the communication between client and server?

Use the packet capture tool of your choice and which is supported on your unknown platform. [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a good choice and you will find plenty of documentation about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you Steffen.

Comment: Hi again, Will this Server only handles ipv4 requests? If I want this server to handle ipv6 request as well, May I please know what changes I need to do?

Comment: @user6453421: This is a new question. Please don't ask it inside a comment but instead create a new question with enough context for others to help you.